# Java 8 List to EnumMap with sums

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following classes:

```
public class Mark {

    private Long id;

    private Student student;

    private Integer value = 0;

    private Subject subject;

}

public enum Subject {

    MATH,
    CHEMISTRY

}
```

I have to receive `EnumMap<Subject, Integer>`, where the value is the sum of all values from the `Mark`.
Example of `List<Mark>`:

> Mark(..., value = 1, subject = MATH)
>   Mark(..., value = 2, subject = MATH)
>   Mark(..., value = 5, subject = CHEMISTRY)

with that value I have to receive the following `EnumMap`:

> MATH             -> 3
>   CHEMISTRY -> 5

I think it should be done with `Collectors::groupingBy`, but I can't understand how to get `EnumMap` and his value.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what's the problem? What do you mean by "I can't understand how to get EnumMap and his value" ? Do you have trouble with understanding how the grouping `Collector` works? Or is the problem related to how can you get an `EnumMap` instead of a `Map` in the end?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 markList.stream().collect(
     groupingBy(
         Mark::getSubject,
         () -> new EnumMap<Subject, Integer>(Subject.class),
         summingInt(Mark::getValue)));
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `Collectors::summingInt`.

Comment: If you assign the result to a variable of `Map<Subject, Integer>` type or use it in any context having a similar target type, you can simplify `() -> new EnumMap<Subject, Integer>(Subject.class)` to `() -> new EnumMap<>(Subject.class)`…