# Kotlin list to EnumMap with sums

Tags: kotlin

I have to migrate my project to Kotlin. Later, I questioned  [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732240/java-8-list-to-enummap-with-sums). And I really can't get how to implement it in Kotlin. I know about 'associateBy' function, but it doesn't have that amount of arguments that Java 8 'groupBy' has.  Is it a way to implement it with lambdas. If not, how can I implement this algorithm without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the easiest solution is to first produce the grouping with [`.groupBy { }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html#groupby) and then process the groups with [`.mapValuesTo() { }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values-to.html), converting them to the sums:

```
val result = marks
        .groupBy(Mark::subject)
        .mapValuesTo(EnumMap(Subject::class.java)) { it.value.sumBy(Mark::value) }
```

After Kotlin 1.1 is released, the new stdlib functionality [shown in Kotlin 1.1 Beta](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#groupingby) will allow you to do the same without the intermediate groups map. Instead, the collection is processed only once with this code:

```
val result = marks
        .groupingBy(Mark::subject)
        .foldTo(EnumMap(Subject::class.java), 0) { acc, it -> acc + it.value }
```

Comment: You can use the `eachCountTo` method instead of `foldTo` on the `Grouping`: `.eachCountTo(EnumMap(Subject::class.java))`

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. I thought he only wanted to count up the marks in each subject.